# What to check to catch error in a Process.run?

Tags: dart, process, keytool

I’m trying to run keytool command with Process.run and if anything goes wrong I want to stop the program. I was checking stderr property of ProcessResult but it also writes it there if it is successfull. So what should I be checking to catch errors and stop the program?

```
await Process.run(
        'keytool',
        [
          '-genkey',
          '-v',
          '-keystore',
          '/Users/figengungor/key.jks',
          '-keyalg',
          'RSA',
          '-keysize',
          '2048',
          '-validity',
          '10000',
          '-alias',
          'key',
          '-dname',
          'cn=Unknown, ou=Unknown, o=Unknown, c=Unknown',
          '-storepass',
          '123456',
        ],)
    .then((ProcessResult results) {
  print('${results.stdout}');
  if (results.stderr != null && results.stderr.toString().isNotEmpty) {
    print('${results.stderr}');
    print('EXIT CODE ${results.exitCode}');
    exit(0);
  }
  print('Keystore file is generated at /Users/figengungor/key.jks');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked exitCode. If it is not zero, then smt is wrong. But error message can be inside stdout or stderr. So I went like this:

```
if(results.exitCode!=0) {
  print('STDOUT ${results.stdout}');
  print('STDERR ${results.stderr}');
  print('EXIT CODE ${results.exitCode}');
  exit(1);
}
```